# diff with or without --brief

Tags: diff

When comparing the file contents of two directories using `diff dirA dirB`, what are the differences between with or without the `--brief` option? As far as I notice, by default `diff` reports only when files differ.

PS - We may add `-r` for recuring into subdirectories, but it does not affect the concern in this question. I personally prefer `no-dereference` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--brief` option only writes a line that two files differ. Without the option, `diff` will print a how those two files are different:

`diff filea fileb`:

```bash
diff texlive_packages.txt texlive_packages2.txt 
384c384
< texlive-encxvlna.noarch
---
> texlive-encxvlsd.noarch
647c647
< texlive-lastpage.noarch
---
> texlive-lastsdde.noarch
```

And the same with the `--brief` option:

```bash
diff --brief texlive_packages.txt texlive_packages2.txt
Files texlive_packages.txt and texlive_packages2.txt differ
```

The latter is similar to how diff reports differences in binary files, etc.